# PHP not uploading file to server

Tags: php, html

I am making some kind of update management for my private android app with PHP. The plan is that I have a HTML form where I select apk file and version of application. When I upload app to my server it would be placed in apk folder and renamed. The problem is that I can't get file uploaded to server. It keeps showing "There is error". Apk folder have 777 rights.

HTML form:

```
<form action="android_u.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <table cellspacing="0" border="0" width="680" style="margin-top:25px;">
            <tr>
                <td><b>APK file:</b></td>
                <td><input type="file" name="apk" placeholder="APK file..." /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><b>Version:</b></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="version" placeholder="Version..." /> (Example: 1.1)</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <input type="image" id="upload" style="margin-left: 580px;" src="templates/images/spacer.png" />
    </form>
```

PHP code:

```
$version = $_REQUEST['version'];

$ver = str_replace(".", "-", $version);

$target_path = "/apk/ind-" . $ver . ".apk"; 
$file = "ind-" . $ver . ".apk";

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['apk']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
$msg = "<div class='msg2'>File uploaded</div>";

$day = date("j");
$month = date("n");
$year = date("Y");
$hour = date("G");
$minute = date("i");

$query = "INSERT INTO android (version, user_id, prenosi, file, year, month, day, hour, minute) VALUES ('$verzija', '$id', '0', '$file', '$year', '$month', '$day', '$hour', '$minute')";
mysql_query($query);

} else {
    $msg = "<div class='msg2'>Error</div>";
}
```

Comment: try dumping $_FILES['apk']['error'] to see if there's an error code.. your issue could be related to upload size. read more about error codes here http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

Comment: dump displays int(1), destination folder is writeable and file size is less than 400 kb

Comment: error 1 = *The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini*

Comment: `target_path = "/apk/ind...` you know that's root/apk/ind...?

Comment: In phpinfo() is upload_max_filesize displayed as 50MB, file is only 400 kB

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, the problem still remains

Comment: what you get `echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` ?

Comment: what is the error response? "There is an error" isn't a PHP response. `error_reporting(E_ALL);` might help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved, thank you for helping.

I changed upload_max_filesize in php.ini from 50MB to 50M and it works.